Can't edit claims in a B2C OpenID Connect Identity Provider
I have an OpenID Connect identity provider configured in my B2C instance.  I put the wrong values in the claims configuration, and Azure's web interface isn't letting me change them.  When I change them, it says my changes were submitted successfully, but if I go back and look at it, they haven't been changed.  I tried deleting the Identity Provider and recreating it with the correct claims values, but the bad values were still in place.
We've opened a ticket with support, and they're telling me to create a custom policy, and edit the XML file to change the fields.  I'm new to Azure, and have no idea how to do that.
Is there any way to make these changes using PowerShell instead of via the web interface?  I've had trouble figuring out the docs, or learning how to find what I need.
Here's more background, in case it helps.  We're building a web app that authenticates against our B2C instance.  Everything about the connection between the web app and B2C works, including the claims.  The app can pick up the first and last names from B2C.
We also have an OpenID Connect identity provider, configured in our B2C instance, which connects to our company's B2B AD instance.  This is so people who work for us can use their work credentials to use the web app.  Authentication works, but the claims don't.  I know that I put the wrong values in the configuration, so it doesn't work.
I'm confused because the problem I'm seeing -- Azure's web app not letting me change the values -- seems like a bug on the MS side, but support is telling me to change the configuration to something different.  We keep getting replies back telling me to edit the XML, but as far as I know there is no XML.

What they are telling you to do is this.
The custom policy is written in XML, hence the XML reference.
If you've never used custom policies, start here.

Thank you for this.  It turned out the XML instructions weren't right for us (we have a user flow, not a custom policy), and that the reason I couldn't update the configuration through the web interface is that I was trying to save an invalid configuration.
